# How to retrieve the size of this array?

Tags: c++, arrays, size

I'm using [IMidiQueue](https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol/blob/master/WDL/IPlug/IMidiQueue.h) to queue/add `IMidiMsg` objects to my `IMidiQueue mMIDICreated;`

At some times, I'd like to retrieve the number of items I've added on it. I've tried this:

```
char buffer[50];
sprintf(buffer, "size %d\n", sizeof(mMIDICreated) / sizeof(IMidiMsg));
OutputDebugString(buffer);
```

but after adding 8 items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    IMidiMsg* one = new IMidiMsg;
    // ...
    mMIDICreated.Add(one);

    IMidiMsg* two = new IMidiMsg;
    // ...
    mMIDICreated.Add(two);
}
```

it returns 2, not 8. Where am I wrong?

Comment: std::extent http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) will return the size of the object or type itself, it's a constant and is evaluated at compile-time, has nothing to do with the number of items which could be known only at run-time.

You should use `IMidiQueue::ToDo`:

> Returns the number of MIDI messages in the queue.

Comment: Wow. Yes, that seems what I need. Why is it called `ToDo`? Typo?

Comment: @markzzz I don't know. The number of messages need to be processed?

Comment: @markzzz I guess the author treated it as a a work queue. The items stored in it are units of work. When you have work to do, well, you get `ToDo`. By the way, that class is pretty much unnecessary. - it's a priority queue, and one should use an off-the-shelf one, not write one from scratch... [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) based on a `std::deque` Container would work.

Comment: @Kuba Ober: `std::priority_queue` doesn't contains a SORT function when you add new element to it (which need to be sorted due to X param). IMidiQueue got it; I use it exclusively for this.

Comment: @markzzz A priority queue is *inherently sorted*, just like a `std::map` is.

Comment: sorted by what? I need to sort it regarding `->offset` property. Can I set it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `mMIDICreated` is a *pointer*, doing `sizeof` on a pointer returns the size of the actual pointer and not what it points to. Also note that when passing an array to a function, it *decays* to a pointer to its first element.

If a function needs the number of elements in an array, you need to pass that along to the function as an argument.

---

An alternate solution, and one that I recommend over using plain arrays/pointers, is to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (for arrays that are known at time of compilation) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for "run-time" or dynamic arrays.

Comment: So every time I add an element I need to "count" (store) the element I add in a variable?

Comment: @markzzz Yes. Or use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your link:

```
class IMidiQueue
{
    ...
    IMidiMsg* mBuf;
}
```

The buffer that stores the elements is not taken into the size returned by `sizeof()`. Only the size of the pointer itself.

However, there is also a method `int GetSize()` that could be useful to you.